# How to connect QNetworkReply signal to progress bar in qt

Tags: c++, qt

In the code below:

```
connect(network_access_manager_, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)),
    this, SLOT(onRequestCompleted_progress(QNetworkReply *)));

    network_access_manager_->get(request);
```

The point is that while the downloading the file via get(request) is in progress I'd like to connect the signal from QNetworkReply to progressBar but I simply don't see how am I suppose to do it? The QNetworkReply is unnamed.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`network_access_manager_->get(request);` returns `QNetworkReply*`, so

```
QNetworkReply *reply = network_access_manager_->get(request);
connect(reply, SIGNAL(downloadProgress(qint64, qint64)), this, SLOT(......))
```

will serve.